# hcsshim: timeout waiting for notification extra info

Tags: docker

We are using docker container for .net core. When we execute build command from window's power shell go the following error message:

hcsshim: timeout waiting for notification extra info

[image]

Here is our docker file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I had this issue now for a couple of days and couldn't really pin point it down.

What did the trick for me was:

- Uninstalling docker
- Removing all docker folders
- Removing the windows features Containers and Hyper-v
- Restart
- Reinstall docker
- Let docker handle the Windows features
- Restart

And that's it...

Comment: To clarify: 
I uninstalled both Docker, and Windows Features: Hyper-v & Containers. Then restarted. Then reinstalled Windows Features. Then Docker. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think in my case the fix was that I needed to run Windows Powershell in Admin mode. However following @halbherz's answer. I uninstalled docker for windows. Un-installation wasn't easy. For uninstalling I had to do following:

- First I tried to uninstall it using uninstaller which got stuck for
  like forever in the end and nothing happened.
- I cancelled the uninstaller which was stuck.
- I deleted the contents of the folder C:\Program Files\Docker,
  manually.
- Ran uninstaller again from Programs and Features which removed the
  entry 'Docker for Windows' from my list of installed programs.

Further I downloaded docker for windows again. Re-installed it again. Ran Windows Powershell in admin mode. Deleted old image, pulled the image again. Tried creating container again and this time it ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

solution worked for me: (windows 10, windows containers)

1. uninstall hyper-v (windows features)
2. restart pc
3. install hyper-v (windows features)
4. restart pc

and it worked to build my container